# Why was this act by Peter Parker needed earlier but not later?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In [Spider-Man: Far from home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home), when Peter and Beck are at the pub, we see that Peter transfers control of EDITH to Beck with a whole voice command and confirmations, but later

> when Beck dies and Peter gets EDITH back

there is no need for commands or confirmation, Peter just gets it.

How does this work?

Comment: Presumably, both Beck **and** Peter would still have access but Beck was the one with the glasses.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Even though Peter transferred EDITH's ownership to Beck, he is still recognised by EDITH's integrated database as an owner/controller. We can infer two possibilities :

1. Even if Peter said he was "transferring" ownership, it didn't remove his access rights to EDITH (and thus Peter can access it as will as long as he can put on the glasses)
2. Tony Stark hard-coded Peter as an owner and Peter literally CANNOT remove his ownership from EDITH. This could be an intelligent counter-measure against

   a) Peter mistakenly transferring ownership (as in the movie),

   b) hacking.

Far From Home does not offer a definitive answer, but these are the two most likely possibilities. (Do note that, in effect, they aren't that different)

Comment: Well, there's a third possibility that Beck, recognizing that his plans were going south, programmed EDITH to respond to Peter's commands but has concealed certain programs like, say, an important illusion so he can get away.

Comment: I think 2 is correct and the reason why Peter said "thank you" after he put the glasses back on and found he still had control. He was saying "thank you" to Tony Stark.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when Tony Stark flashed the firmware, he was "root". Standard practice is to leave the root account alone, and do everything through a superuser account. So he would have a superuser account that he did everything through.

At some point, he transferred the "root" account to Peter.

So at the beginning of the movie, Peter has the root "password" (or rather the root biometrics since people don't use passwords any more.) Obviously he would also have a superuser account that he used to execute commands but it would be like "su -c target Brad" or something like that.

So when he said "transfer control" to Beck, he transferred the "root" account to Beck. So now Beck is "root" (ie. has the root biometrics) but he would also have a superuser account that he issued commands through.

When he got the glasses back, Peter would still have his superuser account, as evidenced when EDITH says "Welcome back, Peter" after confirming his biometrics. That's a configurable welcome message, you can see how it's done here :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171938/how-to-display-welcome-message-in-unix

So when he got them back he would just be like "su- c terminate" and that would just stop it.

Does that make sense?